# Adafruit_DHT not working for python 3 Raspberry Pi 3 B

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, adafruit

This is what i did:

```
git clone https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_DHT.git

cd Adafruit_Python_DHT

sudo apt-get install build-essential python-dev

sudo python setup.py install
```

This^ was given in the github link itself. I did this and my code worked perfectly with DHT11 sensor in python 2.x but its failing with python 3. The error that I'm getting is:

```
RuntimeError: Error accessing GPTO. Make sure program is run as root with sudo!
```

My code is:

```
import Adafruit_DHT
import time

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    humidity, temperature = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(Adafruit_DHT.DHT11,4)
    print(temperature)
    print(humidity)
```

Works perfectly well with python 2, the issue is with python 3. I'm using a Raspberry Pi3 B for the GPIO interface.

Edit: 
I tried `sudo python temper.py`
and it works again, but `sudo python3 temper.py` still doesn't work, with one small change, it doesn't give any errors but now the output is

```
None
None
None
None
```

basically, 'None' appears in place of the sensor value for Temperature and Humidity.

Comment: Well, did you do what the error message tells you to do? If you did and it doesn't help, probably you can get some help on the project's [issues page](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_DHT/issues).

Comment: Nope, i didn't. How do i do this - "RuntimeError: Error accessing GPTO. Make sure program is run as root with sudo!" ?

Comment: My obersvation is quite obvious but...
Did you try using sudo?

Comment: @Pitto Should i try 'sudo python3 <filename.py>' ?

Comment: Check 'Edit:' in my description.

Comment: Ok 1st issue seems to be permission related and now solved.
Now if I was you I'd go and recheck very carefully my wiring and my resistance value.

Comment: I'd do that too, but if the same code works with python 2 and if it doesn't with python 3, don't you think it is something to do with the library/installation part? Because wiring must be right, if not how did it work with python 2?

Comment: Did you try:
sudo python3 setup.py install?

Comment: Just did that and it works! Thanks :)

Comment: You did the install of library for python 2, the same package is not available for python3, you can check the available library installed using `pip list`, and compare it with `pip3 list` (which are the list of library under python3 installation).

Comment: I am happy that this solved your problem, @KrishnakumarM!
If this is the case please select and/or upvote my answer.

Have a nice day.

Comment: The Adafruit_DHT library is deprecated, therefore, use the CircuitPython library. https://learn.adafruit.com/dht-humidity-sensing-on-raspberry-pi-with-gdocs-logging/python-setup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using Python 3 please install the library using the right command:

```
sudo python3 setup.py install
```

Answer (score 1):

For Python3 you would need to use brackets after the print word.

```
print('Temp: {0:0.1f} C  Humidity: {1:0.1f} %'.format(temperature, humidity))
```